# Dependency injection with Hilt is adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_PHONE_STATE permissions automatically for app

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

After I added Hilt dependency for my app follow by [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#setup) with latest version **2.28-alpha**

```
// build.gradle

buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'
    }
}
```

```
// app/build.gradle

...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
}
```

I realize that my app added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_PHONE_STATE permissions automatically.

I checked permissions by way: MyApp -> AppInfo -> Permissions

- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- READ_PHONE_STATE

Although, I have never request those permissions in Manifest.xml file or programmatically.

I try remove Hilt dependency and again check permissions. And I was not see them.

Is it a bug of Hilt? Anyone have the same problem?

**Update: it's really a bug, updating to Hilt latest version solved the problem**
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-hilt/issues/11

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1864) in Dagger 2.28, caused by the `dagger.lint` package lacking a `targetSdkVersion`.  It was fixed in version 2.28.1.

To remove those unwanted permissions, simply upgrade your Dagger dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.29.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.29.1"
}
```